# How to get SQL Value from One Table where a Shared Value Matches in a Second Table?

Tags: sql, select, join

```
Table 1 = "device"
tkmodel name  description
======= ====  ================
300     ABCD  description abcd
300     EFGH  description efgh
115     IJKL  description ijkl
121     MNOP  description mnop
200     QRST  description qrst
115     UVWX  description uvwx
305     WXYZ  description wxyz
300     DCBA  description dcba

Table 2 = "model"
enum name                        tkmodel
==== ==========================  =======
0    Descriptive model name 300  300
1    Descriptive model name 115  115
2    Descriptive model name 200  200
3    Descriptive model name 121  121
4    Descriptive model name 305  305
```

I just want ot preface this by saying I have a very basic understanding of queries and can do somwhat simple queries myself, Im just not sure about this one... I would think it would be some kind of JOIN, but not sure how it would be done?

```
SELECT d.tkmodel, d.name, d.description FROM device d
```

Given the 2 tables above, I want to print out 3 columns. Basically, I want those 3 columns FROM the **"device"** table. But, instead of printing the **"device.tkmodel"** number in table 1 I want match that *"tkmodel"* number to a row in table 2 and print the **"name"** column from that row in table 2.

**So the resulting output I am trying to achieve would look like this below:**

```
device.name  model.name                  device.description
===========  ==========================  ==================
ABCD         Descriptive model name 300  description abcd
EFGH         Descriptive model name 300  description efgh
IJKL         Descriptive model name 115  description ijkl
MNOP         Descriptive model name 121  description mnop
QRST         Descriptive model name 200  description qrst
UVWX         Descriptive model name 115  description uvwx
WXYZ         Descriptive model name 305  description wxyz
DCBA         Descriptive model name 300  description dcba
```

So the goal is to print the data from table 1. But, instead of printing the *"tkmodel"* column shown in table 1, I want to print the corresponding **"model.name"** field from the row in Table 2 where `"device.tkmodel = model.tkmodel"`.

The *"tkmodel"* number in table 2 does NOT repeat, it is a unique value in that table so there should only be one match.

Comment: Could You tell more about keys? I mean primary keys, unique indexes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much info about the database/tables themselves, so I'm not really sure about which are the primary keys, indexes, etc... But, I think Mureinik's answer is correct.

Comment: Ok ;) I just wanted to make sure You are not going the wrong way with the tables desing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic usecase for a [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)):

```
SELECT d.name, m.name, d.description
FROM   device d
JOIN   model m ON d.tkmodel = m.tkmodel
```

Comment: Excellent...! Thanks Mureinik, that's exactly what I needed!